# SU(3) geometry, without (too much) algebra

Tags: group-theory, geometry

Is it possible to give a geometrical introduction to the group SU(3)?
Do you know of one?

Without too much group theory, Lie groups and/or matrix representations.
(Not that I am against that, just asking).

E.g. the group SU(2) has the beautiful parallel to SO(3) and is also related to the stereographical projection.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer: $SU(3)$ "looks like" a product of $S^5$ and $SU(2)$. The map to $S^5$ is just "take the first column and treat it as a vector in $\mathbb R^6$". The preimage of a single point, say $(1,0,0) \in \mathbb C^3$, is the set of all matrices in $SU(2)$ that have the form 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & * & * \\ 
0 & * & *
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the starred $2 \times 2$ submatrix is necessarily in $SU(2)$.

Of course, not every fibration like this is actually a product. The preimages of the upper and lower hemispheres under this map are just $D^5 \times SU(2)$, and the gluing map is a map from the equatorial $4$-sphere to $SU(2)$. The problem is that $\pi_4(SU(2))$ is $Z / 2Z$, and the gluing map is probably the nonzero element, so that it's a twisted product -- a nontrivial bundle.

I know that's not a lot of help, but at least it's a warning that this thing isn't likely to be easy to understand in some simple way.